# Update information from secondary form to primary form

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a problem that I can't solve.

I have two forms named main form and capital form, these two forms work independently
When I store an amount in the capital fund table in the capital fund form, it should be displayed after saving my balance in the main form using the method below, but unfortunately, the control on my sticker returned as null. It will be given.

The following code is the method by which my balance is required to be displayed in the main form

Please advise where there is a problem in my code and how to fix it

with respect

```
public static void UpdateCashCapitalValue(DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm currentForm)
    {
        APPLICATION_CAFE_RESTAURANT.MainForm mainForm = (APPLICATION_CAFE_RESTAURANT.MainForm) currentForm.ParentForm;

        Domain.DataBaseContext dataBaseContext = null;
        try
        {
            dataBaseContext =
                new Domain.DataBaseContext();

            Domain.CashBox cashBox =
                dataBaseContext.CashBoxes
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (cashBox != null)
            {
                mainForm.cashCapitalTextBox.Text = cashBox.CashCapital;
                mainForm.nonCashCapitalTextBox.Text = cashBox.NonCashCapital;
                mainForm.totalCpitalTextBox.Text = cashBox.TotalCapital;
            }
            else
            {
                mainForm.cashCapitalTextBox.Text = $"0 تومان";
                mainForm.nonCashCapitalTextBox.Text = $"0 تومان";
                mainForm.totalCpitalTextBox.Text = $"0 تومان";
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.ExceptionError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataBaseContext != null)
            {
                dataBaseContext.Dispose();
                dataBaseContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please be sure to read [how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If the two forms are independent, then `currentForm.ParentForm` wouldn't have a relationship.  Either use events to have the forms communicate, pass the form reference, or look in `Application.OpenForms` collection to find it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but maybe you can tell me how, I don't have much experience in this field, I don't know exactly what I should do